# RegEx Issue | need to validate range of number

Tags: c#, regex

I would like a regular expression that matches a string that ends in digits between the range `0-17`. For example `test_1.png` or `test_08.png`.

I tried the following:

> `(.*)_(([0-1]\d|[0-7])).png`

but it skips strings with `8` or `9`, ie. `test_9.png`. My string may contain a file name with `0` or without `0`, ie. `test_07.png` or `test_7.png`. How do I modify my RegEx so that no strings get skipped?

Comment: Is test_18.png valid?

Comment: (.*)_((0[0-9])|(1[0-7])).png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the regex to separate out the part with the first digit of `1`:

```
(.*)_(0?\d|1[0-7])\.png
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/3Lta9T)